# How to handle this old method in abstract class?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a abstract class **AbstractLogic**, which contains **methodA()** with default implementation.

Two implementations of abstract class.

**1.Sub1Logic: uses methodA() from abstract class

   2.Sub2Logic: overrides methodA() with different behaviour.**

Now behavior for both classes for methodA() is going to be same.

So I am moving Sub2Logic class method methodA() in abstract class.

I have following design level questions:

1. Should I remove this method from Sub2Logic ? or do I have any annotation to make it useless?
2. Should I remove old implementation from abstract class? or do I have any annotation to make it useless?

This questions because, this is big and old application I dont just want to remove something which was live for many years.

Comment: You have version control, right? Delete it. Delete `methodA` in `AbstractLogic`, delete `methodA` in `Sub1Logic`, move `methodA` from `Sub2Logic` to `AbstractLogic`.

Comment: I am having trouble actually understanding the question. Could you try to describe the question in another way? :)

Comment: So _use_ it. Delete commented out code. Delete unused classes. Delete random redundant comments. Delete unused methods. **Delete it all**.

Comment: @TmP i don't think you nessecarily did, i just can't wrap my head around this sentence.  ''Now behavior for both classes for methodA() is going to be same.
So I am moving Sub2Logic class method methodA() in abstract class.''

Comment: Its not advisable for all application since you have a thought of lived many years in your application and in a assumption that your new approach have not stabilized with your application I'm giving you a suggestion to comment the unused methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I remove this method from Sub2Logic ? or do I have any annotation to make it useless?

You should remove the method completely from `Sub2Logic` after you moved it to the abstract class. Otherwise you have duplicated code and the two placed might evolve different. I mean if someone needs to modify the code one can easily forget the other place.

> Should I remove old implementation from abstract class? or do I have any annotation to make it useless?

If both classes `Sub1Logic` and `Sub2Logic` do not have any differences anymore you should remove both and convert the abstract to a normal class.

> do I have any annotation to make it useless?

Methods that should not be used anymore should be annotated with `@Deprecated` and a `@deprecated` javadoc should be added that explains

- why the method is deprecated
- what could be an issue if it is still used
- what method should be preferred instead.

E.g.

```
/** 
 * @deprecated This method might cause inconsistency when used simultaneously
 * by multiple threads
 * and is replaced by  {@link #threadsafeMethod(int, int) threadsafeMethod}. 
 * It will be removed in later releases.
 */
```

Comment: Yeah, but if `Sub1Logic` has a method that overrides logic in `AbstractLogic`, then marking _that_ method as `@Deprecated` isn't going to help anyone...

Comment: thanks, just to clarify "do not have any differences anymore" only for methodA(). @depricated is just warning? correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @BoristheSpider yeah I see, but the OP said that `Sub1Logic: uses methodA()` so `Sub1Logic` only uses methods from the superclass. So there is no method in `Sub1Logic` that should be marked as deprecated, isn't it?